# MultiSite: new Sites not showing up

Tags: multisite, admin

I have a Multisite installation that I just upgraded to 3.5.2. So far everything has been working great (9 sites); after the upgrade I just went to create two new ones, and I have a problem. Everything below is done as the superadmin who is also the admin for the new sites.

- Network Admin -> Sites does not show the new sites.
- If I try to edit them by tweaking the Edit URL of the Sites menu (`/wp-admin/network/site-info.php?id=13`, with `13` being the number of the new blog that I can see in the database), I get "You do not have permission to access this page."
- However, My Sites does show them.
- When I access the site through My Sites (`/blog-name/wp-admin/`), I see normal interface, and I can visit the site without any problems.

So the question is, how can it happen that a superadmin not see a site? And how do I fix it?

**EDIT**: It seems my new sites got `wp_blogs.site_id = 3`, whereas all of my older ones have `wp_blogs.site_id = 1`. I have no idea how this happened, but my `wp-config.php` also says that `SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE` and `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE` are `3`. I suspect I should not touch `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE`, I guess it says that my default blog the one with `wp_blogs.blog_id = 3`?

Can I change these values to `1` safely? (`SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE`, as well as `wp_blogs.site_id` for all blogs) Is this number referenced anywhere else that I'm overlooking?

I believe I created my last blog (before today's fiasco) well after touching anything in `wp-config.php`. Did WordPress only lately start paying attention to `SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE`, so that things started going wrong only after the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your sites are not under the same network, and you have network 1 and network 3. Normally this would never happen on an average multisite unless plugins are installed that can change this.

*Yes 1 WordPress multisite instance can run multiple networks of blogs, you have accidentally stumbled onto this feature, wordpress.com being a primary user of it*

Navigating and accessing the admin of the other sites, and clicking network admin should give you access to that network, and you will see those 2 sites listed there, but not the others.

If you want to merge them back together, changing the site_id in the blogs table will work. Remember to remove the new network from the sites table, but only after changing the blogs.